# Custom listview click get value

Tags: android

I have create an app working with custom listview. I want to get value from the listview when I clicked and will display values to the textview in the main activity. Below id my clode. Please help me to solve this issue? Thanks & Best Regards!

**1. Main Activity.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGetOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textviewHeadline"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewGetTable"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeFoodList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeButtonFood_Drink"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="610dp">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**2. Custom ListViewList.xml**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idFood"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/index_Food"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/idFood"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**3. MainActivity.java**

```
ListView list_menu;
private TextView textViewGetOrder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list_menu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

    textViewGetOrder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textGetOrder);


    list_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

**4. customelist.java**

```
  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  private final Activity context;
  private final String[] Main_Title;
  private final String[] Subtitle;
  private final String[] idItem;
  private final String[] indexFood;

  public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] main_Title, String[]     subtitle, String[] idItem, String[] indexFood) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, main_Title);
    this.context = context;
    this.Main_Title = main_Title;
    this.Subtitle = subtitle;
    this.idItem = idItem;
    this.indexFood = indexFood;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);

    final TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    titleText.setText(Main_Title[position]);


    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

**// My image.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `Callback` with `ListView` adapter.

```
interface MyCallback{
    Context getContext();
    void onItemClick(String value);
}

public MyListAdapter(MyCallback callback, String[] main_Title, String[] subtitle, String[] idItem, String[] indexFood) {
    super(callback.getContext(), R.layout.mylist, main_Title);
    this.callback = callback;
    this.Main_Title = main_Title;
    this.Subtitle = subtitle;
    this.idItem = idItem;
    this.indexFood = indexFood;
}


    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //
        callback.onItemClick("Pass value to displayed on Main activity");
    }
});


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list_menu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,...)
        list_menu.setAdapter(adapter);

        textViewGetOrder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textGetOrder);


        list_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```